# r - Make adjacency matrix with tcrossprod capturing only positive values

Tags: r, matrix

I need to create an adjacency matrix from a dataframe using `tcrossprod`, but the resulting matrix needs to obey a restriction that I will explain below. Consider the following dataframe:

```
z <- data.frame(Person = c("a","b","c","d"), Man_United = c(1,0,1,0))
z
  Person Man_United
1      a      1
2      b      0
3      c      1
4      d      0
```

I make an adjacency matrix from `z` using `tcrossprod`.

```
x <- tcrossprod(table(z))
diag(x) <- 0
x
      Person
Person a b c d
     a 0 0 1 0
     b 0 0 0 1
     c 1 0 0 0
     d 0 1 0 0
```

I need the resulting adjacency matrix to indicate a tie (here signaled with the number 1), only when both persons have value 1 in the original dataframe (i.e. are fans of Manchester United, in this example). For example, persons "a" and "c" of dataframe `z` are fans, so in the resulting adjacency matrix I want their intersecting cell to be valued 1. That works fine here. However, persons "b" and "d" are not fans, and the fact that both have value 0 in the original dataframe does not mean that they are connected in any meaningful way. `tcrossprod`, however, produces a matrix that suggests that they are in fact connected.

How to use `tcrossprod` in a way that it caputures only the positve values of dataframes in producing adjacency matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may restrict attention on `table` results of ones with

```
tcrossprod(table(z)[, "1"])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[# 1,]    1    0    1    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    1    0    1    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0
```

or, if you want to preserve the names,

```
tcrossprod(table(z)[, "1", drop = FALSE])
#       Person
# Person a b c d
#      a 1 0 1 0
#      b 0 0 0 0
#      c 1 0 1 0
#      d 0 0 0 0
```

If there can be more nonzero values, then you may replace `"1"` by `-1` as to eliminate the column for zeroes.

Comment: Julius, a quick follow up. Do the square brackets [,"1", drop = F] also work for occassions in which the table function produces multiple columns? You solution works for binary tables but I'm getting an error for tables from no-nbinary variables (e.g. "dislikes", "neutral", "likes" Man_United. I can update the question if that helps.

Comment: @NBK, the idea is that you want only some of the columns of `table(z)`. In the binary case you wanted the one named "1", while when there are options "0", "1", "2", "3", you could use `[, -1, drop = FALSE]` as to drop the column of "0". So, ultimately you need to select the needed columns, and the best way to do that will depend on what the possible values are. (Maybe `-1`, maybe `3:10`, maybe something with `%in%`.)

Comment: I see. But why you select using quotes? When I use your script without the quotes it works, but not with them. (This is me not knowing the internal workings of the functions -- thanks for the clarifications)

Comment: @NBK, `"1"` select the column *named* "1", which actually is the second column, while `-1` drops the first column (whose name is "0").

Comment: Got it. Thanks.